# Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Tags: cors, swagger, documentation

I'm trying to make a request to my local API from the Swagger documentation, but it always gives this error when I make the request

[image]

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Just got the same problem. Seems my network driver was down or something. Socket couldn't open. After reboot everything was back.
No clue about the root cause, I'm interested if you find something or if a reboot helped you too

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, na verdade o problema estava na própria API que eu estava tentando acessar.

Comment: @IagoAlexandre What was the problem? I'm still having this same problem

Comment: I just had this problem. After a few hours trying to figure out what was causing it I found that it was related to a Cookie I was adding to the response. The problem was that the Cookie was too big but there was no error indicating the actual problem.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, along with your attempts to reoslve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check that your address is not blocked by cors, for dev tests you can use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`.
If it doesn't work for you, check that you are not using an extension on your browser, such as those that block ads. You delete it from your browser, restart it and test again, it will work.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was accessing the web application via 127.0.0.1:3000, once I changed it to localhost:3000, it worked, hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

after Starting IIS Express ...
web API register on 2 URL,
one port is for http, and the other one is for https.
when you call http port you see this error:Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
change the port to https Port.

Answer (score 3):

In `swagger.json` I accidently sat my host port to `http://localhost:3000` and my server was running on port `:5000`.
Once I updated the host port to match the one I'm using to send my requests using swagger ui, the problem's gone.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the "http" option at the run icon on the top of the screen:
[image]

Comment: this suggestion could be useful but it is not totally clear what you are setting the http option for. It's helpful to explain external links

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an edge-case situation, but if you are running from a container, ensure you are doing your port forwarding correctly.

[image]

As one of the answers above states, your application should be running on `localhost:<port_of_choice>` instead of `127.0.0.1:<port_of_choice>`

Comment: Too, for me it was as simple, as changing the actual port of my backend.

Answer (score 1):

With Open API Swagger Implementation, it worked for me by adding this to main application class.

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
  servers = {
    @Server(url = "/myapp/", description = "Default Server URL")
  }
)
```

This allows both http and https connections without needing to select the scheme explicitly. So, both local (http) and dev server (https) works good.

Comment: Thanks! It did not fix my issue, but the issue was related to Open API `server`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not that stupid, i had the exact same message and my db was actually not ready ;) I run npm start in the terminal and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For all users that also use FastApi, this resolved my issue:

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

# Define CORS settings
origins = ["*"]  # Allow requests from any origin

# Add CORS middleware
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was encounter with same issue -To solve this make sure the port at which your application is running and port mention in server.js (servers URL ) of swagger is same.
[image]

And then try again
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35675717)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is stupid but check if the server is runing

Comment: Yes, that's stupid: if the server would not be running, the error message would look different